# Ember View not observing property changes

Tags: ember.js

I am new to Ember and I am trying to use an Ember View to observe a property change in my controller. I am able to log the view, but the handler doesn't fire when the property changes.

I am basically trying to learn the Ember way to remove an item from the view when the user clicks to delete a record. I haven't found really a good guide on this. Any advice is appreciated.

Please let me know if I'm leaving anything out. Thanks in advance!

(This is an inherited codebase; we aren't ready to upgrade Ember yet.)

> Ember v1.0.0-rc.3

#### Route

```
this.resource('posts');
```

```js
App.PostsRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({ // extension of Em.Route
  model: function() {
    return App.Post.list(); // returns a list of posts
  },

  events: {
    // renders a modal in the post context
    showDeleteModal: function(model) {
      this.render('modals/_confirmation', {
        into: 'posts',
        outlet: 'modal',
        controller: 'post'
      });

      this.controllerFor('post').set('model', model);
    }
  }
});
```

#### Controller

```js
App.PostsController = Em.ObjectController.extend(App.PagedTable, Ember.Evented, {
  // ...
});

App.PostController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  foo: false,

  del: function() {
    this.set('foo', true);
  }
});
```

#### View

```js
App.PostsView = Em.View.extend();

App.PostView = Em.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    console.log('Inserted!');
  },

  test: function() {
    console.log('Observed!');
  }.observes('controller.foo')
});
```

#### Template

```
{{#each data in currentDataBlocks itemController="post" itemViewClass="App.PostView"}}
  <tr>
    <td>Stuff</td>
    <td>Stuff</td>
    <td>Stuff</td>
    <td>Stuff</td>
    <td><button class="icon-trash" {{action showDeleteModal data}}></button></td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}

<!-- ... -->

{{outlet modal}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way, in my opinion, to manage a list of items in a view would be to create a property  of the list, containing only the items that needs to be presented, and iterate on this list in the view.

Using your example (with a few alterations for simplicity) I would do the following:

Controller:

```
PostsController = Em.ObjectController.extend(....
    fooDataBlocks: function(){
        return this.get("currentDataBlocks").filter(function(dataBlock){
            return dataBlock.get("foo");
        }
    }.property("currentDataBlocks.@each.foo")
);
```

Template:

```
{{#each data in fooDataBlocks...}}
   ...
{{/each}}
```

As a rule of thumb, always prefer using properties over observers if possible.
This way the value is cached and computed only when needed, not on every single change.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to offer a solution. This does seem like a better way to handle what I'm doing. I'll try this!

Comment: Good advice, but it doesn't really explain why the observer on the view doesn't work. I'd like to know that.

Comment: @neverfox: create a jsbin and I'll have a look.

Comment: On modern projects please use the arrayComputed method.